# prettyfaces with managedbean

Tags: jsf, managed-bean, prettyfaces

I try to give to my managed bean an attribute with prettyfaces:

```
<url-mapping id="inscription1">
    <pattern value="/inscription-#{/[1]/registerManagedBean.actionStr}.html" />
    <view-id value="/WEB-INF/base/register.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
```

In my viem `#{registerManagedBean.actionStr}` gives me the good value (1) but in the managedBean actionStr equals null value (println in constructor).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot read the value in the construct because it is injected AFTER the constructor gets executed. But you can use something like an URL action instead. This one will be executed AFTER the value has been injected.